# In storyboard my views are messed up. Why is that?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode9

I'm using Xcode 9 Version 9.1 (9B55). There is something strange happening in a storyboard. Some of my views are are messed up, and I don't know what is the reason.
It looks like this: 
**EDITED**

[image]

However, all my constraints are set right, and when I run the project on different simulators and on a physical device, everything looks fine. Here how it looks on a simulator/physical device:
[image]

I don't know what is the reason for this kind of behaviour but it makes impossible to work in a storyboard. I think, this problem has appeared quite recently. Sometimes, after reloading the Xcode, views again look fine, but when I start working with storyboard (adding new views, changing constraints or even just tapping on a constraint to see its constant), they again become messed up. Does anybody have this kind of issue, and how this could be solved?

Comment: show the storyboard

Comment: @DamianRzeszot, you mean the document outline or what? The first image is the photo of my storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing and opening Storyboard, the issue goes away! I think it's just an issue in x-code 9.

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes it works for me, sometimes no. I think, stack views have some trouble with labels, which have 0 lines, because all this stuff started to happen when I changed one of my label's number of line.

Comment: Working with Stack views is a BIG problem in Xcode 9.1. I downloaded Xcode 9.2 beta but the release notes do not mention anything about the issue. As of now, the only way to see if the Stackview autolayouts are working or not is to run the project and in the simulator. IB Storyboards are simply not useful. Very painful :(.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, try changing the spacing on one of your stack views instead of closing and reopening Xcode. Toggling the spacing brings back the views in my case.

Comment: Yes, but after some other change, for example, after changing the font (not its size) in one of the labels the views again move from their place and so on

Comment: True, each incremental change toggles between good and bad states. Will need to wait for a fix from Apple. In the meantime, I just toggle something to get a quick view when I'm designing

Comment: Yeah, I hope they'll fix that soon